# C# Use datatable in a new function

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, autocad-plugin

I have a datatable that is defined and filled from data in a spreadsheet. Then, in another function I want to access that data table to cast those values as text into an attribute. How do I use that same datatable in tht DrawCircuits function?

```
public static System.Data.DataTable ReadExcelToTable(string path)
    {
        string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';";
        System.Data.DataSet set = new DataSet();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            System.Data.DataTable sheetsName = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "Table" });
            string firstSheetName = sheetsName.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", firstSheetName);
            OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connstring);
            ada.Fill(set);
            conn.Close();
        }
        return set.Tables[0];
    }

 //this command can insert a block and fill out attributes (text)
    [CommandMethod("DrawCircuits")]
    public void DrawCircuits(string name, double x, double y, double z)
    {
        Database db = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
        using (Transaction myT = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            //Get the block definition
            string blockName = name;
            BlockTable bt =
                db.BlockTableId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
            BlockTableRecord blockDef =
              bt[blockName].GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;
            //Also open paper space - we'll be adding our BlockReference to it
            BlockTableRecord ps =
              bt[BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace].GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite)
                                                      as BlockTableRecord;
            //Create new BlockReference, and link it to our block definition
            Point3d point = new Point3d(x, y, z);
            using (BlockReference blockRef =
                    new BlockReference(point, blockDef.ObjectId))
            {
                //Add the block reference to  paper space
                ps.AppendEntity(blockRef);
                myT.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(blockRef, true);
                //Iterate block definition to find all non-constant
                // AttributeDefinitions                                        
                foreach (ObjectId id in blockDef)
                {                       
                    DBObject obj = id.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                    AttributeDefinition attDef = obj as AttributeDefinition;
                    if ((attDef != null) && (!attDef.Constant))
                    {
                        //This is a non-constant AttributeDefinition
                        //Create a new AttributeReference
                        using (AttributeReference attRef = new AttributeReference())
                        {
                            attRef.SetAttributeFromBlock(attDef, blockRef.BlockTransform);
// below is where I want to access the
// datatable loaded into memory in the other
// function. I want the att.Ref.TextString 
// value to start from row 0 column 0 of the 
 // datatable                            
                          if (attRef.Tag == "TAG1")
                           {
                               attRef.TextString = "";
                           }
                           if (attRef.Tag == "XXX-NNNN+")
                           {
                               attRef.TextString = "";
                           }
                            //Add the AttributeReference to the BlockReference
                            blockRef.AttributeCollection.AppendAttribute(attRef);
                            myT.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(attRef, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Our work here is done
            myT.Commit();
        }
    }
```

***8-18-2016 update!
With help, I have been able to use the datatable I loaded into memory from an Excel spreadsheet in a new function by way of calling in in the parameter of the DrawCircuits() function. I think this is the best method for what I am trying to achieve. However, I am now, once again, trying to use this datatable in another function where I tied everything together that I am trying to use, Test3(). Everything works fine and the attRef.TextString = dr.Table.Rows[1][0].ToString(); statement from the DrawCircuits() function works properly by populating the value from the datatable as a string for the attribute.

The problem that I am having is that now, in another function, Test3(), I cannot get the for loop of Test3() to populate the next group of attributes with the next row of the datatable. All of the attributes get populated with the same row values from the datatable. I have tried many attempts at this on my own. Let me know if any of you have any ideas about the right solution.

```
[CommandMethod("Test3")]
    public void Test3()
    {
        string Path = SelectSpreadsheet();
        System.Data.DataTable table = ReadExcelToTable(Path);

        InsertBlocks();
        DrawModule("AI-1756-IF16H-SHEET1");
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            DrawCircuits("AI-AIT-CIRCUIT", 24, 17 - (i * 1), 0, table.Rows[i]);
        }

    }

public static System.Data.DataTable ReadExcelToTable(string path)
    {
        string connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';";
        System.Data.DataSet set = new DataSet();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            System.Data.DataTable sheetsName = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "Table" });
            string firstSheetName = sheetsName.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", firstSheetName);
            OleDbDataAdapter ada = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connstring);
            ada.Fill(set);
            conn.Close();
        }
        return set.Tables[0];
    }


[CommandMethod("DrawCircuits")]
    public void DrawCircuits(string name, int x, int y, int z, System.Data.DataRow dr)
    {
        Database db = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
        using (Transaction myT = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            //Get the block definition
            string blockName = name;
            BlockTable bt =
                db.BlockTableId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
            BlockTableRecord blockDef =
              bt[blockName].GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;
            //Also open paper space - we'll be adding our BlockReference to it
            BlockTableRecord ps =
              bt[BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace].GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite)
                                                      as BlockTableRecord;
            //Create new BlockReference, and link it to our block definition
            Point3d point = new Point3d(x, y, z);
            using (BlockReference blockRef =
                    new BlockReference(point, blockDef.ObjectId))
            {
                //Add the block reference to  paper space
                ps.AppendEntity(blockRef);
                myT.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(blockRef, true);
                //Iterate block definition to find all non-constant
                // AttributeDefinitions    


                    foreach (ObjectId id in blockDef)
                    {

                        DBObject obj = id.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                        AttributeDefinition attDef = obj as AttributeDefinition;
                        if ((attDef != null) && (!attDef.Constant))
                        {
                            //This is a non-constant AttributeDefinition
                            //Create a new AttributeReference


                            using (AttributeReference attRef = new AttributeReference())
                            {
                                attRef.SetAttributeFromBlock(attDef, blockRef.BlockTransform);


                                if (attRef.Tag == "TAG1")
                                {

                                    attRef.TextString = dr.Table.Rows[1][0].ToString();
                                }
                                if (attRef.Tag == "XXX-NNNN+")
                                {
                                    attRef.TextString = dr.Table.Rows[1][1].ToString();
                                }

                                //Add the AttributeReference to the BlockReference
                                blockRef.AttributeCollection.AppendAttribute(attRef);
                                myT.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(attRef, true);
                            }


                        }
                    }


            }
            //Our work here is done
            myT.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Either add it as a field, or pass it as a parameter.

Comment: I did try to pass the table as a parameter but was not able to get it to work. Passing it through as a parameter might be the best way since I the DrawCircuits() function is in a for loop. Do you have an example of how I would do this?

Comment: `public void DrawCircuits(DataTable dt, string name, double x, double y, double z)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static System.Data.DataTable ReadExcelToTable(string path)
{
    //Method codes
    ...

    // Return the data table
    return set.Tables[0];
}    

public void DrawCircuits(string name, double x, double y, double z,DataTable dt)
{
     ...
     attRef.TextString = dt.Rows[0][0];
     ...
}

public DataTable ChangeDt(DataTable dt)
{
    // Change dt codes
    ...
    // Return changed dt
    return dt;
}

public void Use(DataTable dt)
{
    var myDt = ChangeDt(dt);

    for(i=0; i<=10; i++)
    {
       DrawCircuits("name", 1, 2, i, myDt);
    }
}
```

Or a `Use` method without parameter:

```
public void Use()
{
    var dt = ReadExcelToTable("....The Path....");
    var myDt = ChangeDt(dt);
    for(i=0; i<=10; i++)
    {
       DrawCircuits("name", 1, 2, i, dt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks RAM. The parameter method worked and I think it is the best approach. I was able to target the rows of the datatable and populate my necessary attributes with strings. The only issue now is that I am getting an error that says: cannot convert from System.Data.DataRow to System.Data.DataTable

Comment: You are assigning a `System.Data.DataRow` value to a variable or parameter of `System.Data.DataTable` type. You should change type of the target variable or parameter from `DataTable` to name of your custom `DataRow` type.

Comment: Thanks again RAM. So, you were right in your previous comment Aug 12. I found the incompatible parameter/value disagreement in the code and fixed it by your advice.

Comment: @BenSiewert, I'm happy that you solved it. If you think my answer was right then please accept it by click on its check mark. ;)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your help. I also was able to learn something new since I am a beginner at programming. I do enjoy it. I have one more minor problem to solve with the code. How do I submit on this page what my code currently looks like and what I am trying to fix?

Comment: @BenSiewert, you can learn many things in `stackoverflow`. If you have other problems, **first search** your problem topic in **google** or **stackoverflow**. They usually forward you to some question about that problem. If you search enough but you did not find any related result, **then write a new question** about it and put **necessary information and codes about that problem** in it. Also i recommend you to read this guideline: **[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.